# Sample size calculation for a non-inferiority RCT

Tags: sample-size, clinical-trials, non-inferiority

I am planning to test the non-inferiority of a new resistance training program compared to the standard training program. The primary outcome will be maximal muscle strength that will be measured pre and post the intervention, alongside other secondary outcomes - all of which are continuous variables.

To calculate the sample size, I need to come up with two types of data: 1) the mean and SD of the primary outcome and 2) decide on a clinically significant value to establish the delta.

Q1- Do I need the mean and SD of pre-post intervention differences or alternatively, only the pre-intervention values?

Q2- What will be a recommended source for the mean and SD? Will a large enough RCT with a similar intervention and outcomes be an appropriate source for the mean and SD?

Q3- I am not confident that I fully understand the meaning of the delta here. Does in concern absolute or standardized differences between the two interventions? Some simple clarification as to what the delta means here would be helpful.

Q4- If there isn't an established clinically significant difference - is there another way to calculate or closely estimate delta?

Comment: A passing comment on #3-- delta here is the level of difference that you would consider acceptable in labelling the new treatment as non-inferior (i.e. how big a difference is OK before you would say the new treatment is worse). In any sample size estimation it would typically be framed in the original units of the outcome (maximal muscle strength).

Comment: Thank you @JamesStanley How would you handle the natural variability between men/women/lower extremity/upper extremity..? Selecting a specific value can be inaccurate. Would you standardize in this case?